# Python bottle app gets lots of requests In Openshift production environment even though there is no requests

Tags: python, openshift, bottle

I created a python bottle app and deployed successfully on openshift (rhcloud). Everything is good so far. However whenever I check server logs, I see excessive amount of requests are coming to homepage handler. It's a new site and only myself know the address. It's impossible that people request it.
When I log the user-agent, it comes as `None` interestingly.
`path_shift` request variable contains this: http://ex-std-node542.prod.rhcloud.com/ - AFAIK, it's some kind of an openshift tool.
Is it related to haproxy? I enabled scaling. Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is haproxy making requests to your applications gears to make sure that they are running so that it can route requests to them.  You can modify the configuration by editing the haproxy.cfg file on your main gear.